# p-value and t-distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given a data set $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, ( for $n$ - large ) which is realization of a random sample $(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$. Assume the null hypothesis $H_0:\mu = \mu_0$ and alternative hypothesis $H_1 : \mu > \mu_1$ . Then which is an appropriate method of testing whether or not to reject $H_0$?

One way would be to use $t$-test method and find $\pm t_{n-1,\alpha/2}$ ( if $\alpha$ - the significance level is given ) and check where our current observation $T_0 = (X_{\text{average}} - \mu_0)/(S_n/\sqrt n)$ lies. But I also thought about computing the probability that $T$ is at least as extreme as our current our observation ( i.e just compute the $p$-value $P(T > T_0)$. My question is when to use p-value and when t-distribution as a motivation for a decision whether to reject $H_0$.

Comment: I would use p-value when there are no unknowns (for $u_0, n$). So I just GC to do that. But if there's unknowns, I use $t$. (Side note: $t$ is used for small $n$ where $n<20$. For large $n$, you can use $Z- Test$.)

Comment: Note that $t_{n-1,\alpha/2}$ is for two-sided tests, here you have a one-sided test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you select the type-I error level ($\alpha$) the two approaches are strictly equivalent. This is explained in most introductory stats books.

For a one-sided test like yours:
$$
t>t_{n-1,\alpha} \text{ iff } p<\alpha.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Both methods use the $\mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1),$ Student's t distribution
with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom.

**Background.** Suppose we have a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a normal distribution with unknown population mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$ We want to use the data to test $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_a: \mu > \mu_0.$

We will reject $H_0$ when the statistic $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ is sufficiently large. Here $\bar X$ is the sample mean
(estimating $\mu)$ and $S$ is the sample standard deviation (estimating $\sigma).$

If the null hypothesis is true, then $T \sim \mathsf{T}(n-1).$

**Method 1: Fixed significance level.** uses a fixed significance level $\alpha,$ often 0.05. Then one can use printed tables of the t distribution or statistical software
to find the critical value $c$ that cuts probability from the upper tail of $\mathsf{T}(n-1).$

For example, if $\alpha = 0.05$ and $n = 15$ one can find that $c = 1.761.$ You should look at a printed t table (row $\nu = 14, perhaps, depending on the style of the table, column headed 0.05 or 0.95) to find this value. The computation from R statistical software is shown below:

```
qt(.95, 14)
[1] 1.76131
```

Continuing the example, suppose that  $\mu_0 = 20, \bar X = 22.50,$ and $S = 3.75.$  Thus $$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}} = 
\frac{22.50 - 20}{3.75/\sqrt{15}} =  2.582 >  c = 1.7613,$$
so that we reject $H_0.$

**Method 2: P-value.** The P-value is the probability of the occurrence of a value of $T$ that is as extreme, or more extreme (in the direction of the alternative), than the observed value $T = 2.582.$ This probability is calculated using the distribution $\mathsf{T}(n-1).$  However, P-values require statistical software. Only is a few special cases can you get exact P-values from printed tables.) The computation of the P-value in this example using R statistical software is shown below:

```
1 - pt(2.582, 14)
[1] 0.01086239
```

Here is how the P-value is used in deciding whether to reject $H_0:$
If we choose to test at level $\alpha = 0.05,$ then we reject $H_0$ if
the P-value is smaller than 0.05, which it is.

Also, if we want to test at level $\alpha = 0.02,$ then we rejject
because the P-value $= 0.011 < 0.02.$  By contrast, we cannot (quite) reject
at level $\alpha = 0.01$ because the P-value (just slightly) exceeds 0.01.$

**Graphical summary.** Here is a plot of the density curve of the distribution $\mathsf{T}(n-1).$ 
The critical value $c = 1.7613$ is shown as a vertical dotted line.
The area under the density curve to the right of this line is the
significance level $0.05 = 5\%.$ The observed value 2.582 of the $T$-statistic is shown as a solid vertical line. The (tiny) area under the curve
to the right of this line is the P-value.

[image]

**This test in Minitab statistical software.** The printout below (slightly edited for relevance) shows how Minitab statistical software
reports results of this test. Notice that here, as in most statistical software, the output 
provides a P-value, but not a critical value for any particular
significance level.

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 20 vs > 20


 N     Mean   StDev   SE Mean      T       P
15   22.500   3.750     0.968   2.58   0.011
```